# Need to find the free appointments in my second table

Tags: sql, oracle, join, outer-join, appointment

So ive got my first table with Vets in it..

```
Vet 1/Branch 5  
Vet 2/Branch 5
Vet 3/Branch 6
Vet 4/Branch 6
```

Second Table has appointments in it...

```
Appointment1...1stJanuary...Vet1
Appointment2...2ndJanuary...Vet3
Appointment3...2ndJanuary...Vet4
```

Is there any way to look at the second table when querying with 1st January/Branch 5 and return "Vet 2", as they are not 'booked' at that time/they are 'available'

```
SELECT STAFF.FIRST_NAME, STAFF.LAST_NAME
FROM STAFF
FULL OUTER JOIN APPOINTMENT
ON STAFF.STAFF_NO=APPOINTMENT.STAFF_NO
WHERE STAFF.BRANCH_NO='00005'
AND STAFF.JOB_DESC='Vet'
AND APPOINTMENT.APP_DATE_TIME='28-JUL-02';
--AND STAFF.STAFF_NO IS NOT NULL;
```

Heres what I tried if you get my idea... the last line didn't work I imagine because 'Vet 2' doesn't have a corresponding '28-JUL-02' in the right table. Is there anything that will work?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `NOT EXISTS`?

```
SELECT S.FIRST_NAME, S.LAST_NAME
FROM STAFF S
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM APPOINTMENT A
                  WHERE A.STAFF_NO = S.STAFF_NO AND
                        A.APP_DATE_TIME = DATE '2002-07-28'
                 ) AND
     S.BRANCH_NO='00005' AND
     S.JOB_DESC = 'Vet';
```

Comment: I could very well be. I can't wait to be an expert at this. Let me have another crack at this with your help. Thank you very much.